# how to send html form value to php in same file without using action

Tags: php, html, action

below code is strored into my database....

This Program is working very well at localhost but i want to run it on Online PHP Editor as

https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_intro

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    // Check if the form is submitted
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Retrieve the form values
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        
        // Process the form data or perform any other actions
        // ...
        
        // Display the submitted values
        echo "<p>Name: $name</p>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

or what i do that both HTML and PHP code run on same Online Editor not offline/localhost

Comment: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` there translates to `prog.php`, however `prog.php` returns a 404 error. If you want to run this at an online editor, basically you need to figure out how that editor is wired, and to what URL specifically, in whatever frame or other receptacle, the form should be sent. Is there a particularly good reason you want to run this in an online editor?